# Is the subspace of $ C_0 $ open in $ L^\infty $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

$C_0$ is the set of all sequences that converge to $0$ , and $L^\infty$ is the set of all bounded sequences, , is $C_0$ open in $L^\infty$?

Comment: Which metric you assume, the one of $L^\infty$, i.e., the maximum one, right?

Comment: Yes, the sup metric

Comment: Here I thought that the only open subspace is the whole space: Any open ball centered at $0$ contains a basis, and scales to the whole space.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The constant $\varepsilon$ sequence is in the $2\varepsilon$-ball around $0$.

Comment: +1 You managed to give the simplest argument of all of us :-)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly we notice $C_0$ is a complete metric space hence it is a closed subset of $L^{\infty}$

Now observe that $L^{\infty}$ is connected therefore the only closed and open sets are the empty set and the whole space.

Hence $C_0$ cannot possibly be open.

Comment: why exactly is $L^\infty$ connected? Or to be more precise, what do I need such that $L^\infty(X,\mu) $ is connected?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis here I assumed that $L^{\infty}$ is the space of real valued sequences endowed norm. In this case connectedness is implied because our space is path connected.

Answer (score 0):

The metric on $L^\infty$ is usually taken to be $$d(x,y) = \sup_k |x_k - y_k|.$$ Note that $$\vec 0 = (0,0,0,\ldots) \in C_0,$$ but for any $\epsilon > 0$, $$\vec \epsilon = (\epsilon,\epsilon,\epsilon,\ldots) \notin C_0,$$ even though $d(\vec 0,\vec \epsilon) = \epsilon$.  Thus $\vec 0$ is not an interior point of $C_0$.

Comment: This makes absolute sense! I too thought it was closed!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative.

The always vanishing sequence $\mathcal O$ belongs to $C_0$ and for all $\epsilon >0$ the sequence whose terms are all equal to $\epsilon$ doesn't belong to $C_0$ but it's distance to $\mathcal O$ is equal to $\epsilon$.